# Proof: "If the list is then k-sorted for some smaller integer k, then the list remains h-sorted"

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, correctness-proof

> Shellsort is a generalization of insertion sort that allows the
>   exchange of items that are far apart. The idea is to arrange the list
>   of elements so that, starting anywhere, considering every hth element
>   gives a sorted list. Such a list is said to be h-sorted. Equivalently,
>   it can be thought of as h interleaved lists, each individually
>   sorted. Beginning with large values of h, this rearrangement allows
>   elements to move long distances in the original list, reducing large
>   amounts of disorder quickly, and leaving less work for smaller h-sort
>   steps to do. **If the list is then k-sorted for some smaller integer
>   k, then the list remains h-sorted.** Following this idea for a
>   decreasing sequence of h values ending in 1 is guaranteed to leave a
>   sorted list in the end.

[[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort)]

*What is the mathematical proof for the quoted claim (in bold)?*

**An attempt at the proof** (for the case when number of elements is $2n+1$):

---

My initial array is $A = \{x_0, \cdots, x_n\}$ and i have $x_0 < x_n$. Say that after first pass $x_0$ switches place with $x_m$, so the final array $B$ starts with the entry $x_m$ regardless of the position of $x_0$ (which can further switch place with $x_{2m}$ and so on). Thus, $x_m < x_0$. Now, in the final pass $x_n$ can switch place with $x_k$ (which, before the last pass, is in the $(n-m)$-th position in the array). We don't care about $k$, but we just know that $x_n < x_k$. So the last entry in the final $m$-sorted array $B$ is $x_k$.
Sum it up: $x_m < x_0 < x_n < x_k$.

That means $B$ is $n$-sorted.
If we assumed the switchings of $x_0$ and $x_n$ didn't happen during $m$-sorting, we are trivially done, because the starting and final entries of $B$ are $x_0$ and $x_n$ respectively, and since $x_0 < x_n$, $B$ is $n$-sorted.

Say $A = \{x_0, \cdots, x_n, \cdots, x_{2n}\}$ is $n$-sorted. We can assume the subarray $\{x_0, \cdots, x_n\}$ is $m$-sorted WLOG and because of what we proved earlier. Suppose now that while $m$-sorting, $x_n$ and $x_{n+m}$ are switched; then $x_{n+m} < x_n$. And then on the last entry, $x_k$ (in the $2n-m$ th position) and $x_{2n}$ are switched. Then $x_{2n} < x_k$.

After the $m$-sorting is over, the $n$-gap subarray starting at $x_0$ is $\{x_0, x_{n+m}, x_k\}$. We have $x_0 < x_m < x_{n+m} < x_n < x_{2n} < x_k$, where $x_m < x_{n+m}$ is because $A$ is $n$-sorted.

So, this is proof that if a $2n+1$ array is $m$-sorted after being $n$-sorted, it remains $n$ sorted.

---

However, I don't know how to generalize that for any size of array.

Comment: What do you mean by "remains h-sorted"?  What is the remains?  You haven't said anything about any changes to the list.  Are you changing the list?  Please edit the question to make it self-contained, so we don't have to click some external link to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. I quoted the entire paragraph from Wikipedia which contains the sentence. Is it okay now?

Comment: I agree. This question only makes sense looking at (a specific form of?) Shellsort. (By the way, you may want to get a textbook. The average quality of algorithms articles on Wikipedia is dreadful.)

Comment: @Raphael It's applicable for any shell-sort. (Say) In the first step if a list is 6-sorted, then the sentence claims that even if you 5-sort, or 4-sort,or ...., or 1-sort it; the list *remains* 6-sorted.

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to find a proof you're looking for. Knuth has a pretty clear one in *TAOCP*, v.3. [If you don't know what that is, look it up; it should be a reference on the shelves of every computer scientist.]

Answer (score 2):

the claim follows easily from a careful definition of "*k*-sorted". *define k-sorted* as "for all *i* there does not exist a *j > k* such that for two elements in the list *a[i+j] < a[i]*." then if a list is *k*-sorted, it is h-sorted for *h > k.*

to look into deeper/ more general theory realize that *k-sorted* is a *"measure of disorder"* eg as in question [how to measure sortedness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11836/how-to-measure-sortedness). see this paper [a survey of adaptive sorting algorithms,](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.8017) / Castro, Wood, measures of disorder, sec 1.2. *h-sorted* appears to be equivalent to measure #1, *Dis*, "largest distance determined by an inversion".